# Как сделать приближение камеры с видом сверху в 2d игре без движка и доп. библиотек (Java)

Tags: java, камера, render

Ситуация — надо сделать приближение в игре совсем без движка и других библиотек, так что язык не так важен

На данный момент я имею:

- Класс Object:

```
public class Object implements HasPosition, HasModel, HasHitbox {
    
    private double x;
    private double y;
    private double z;
    
    private Point[] hitbox;
    private Pixel[] pixels;
    public int[] spinCenter = new int[2];
} // остальное не важно
```

- Класс Pixel:

```
public class Pixel extends Point {
    
    public int color;
    
    public Pixel() {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        z = 0;
        color = 0;
    }
    
    
    public Pixel(double x, double y, double z, int color) {
        super(x, y, z);
        this.color = color;
    }
    
}
```

- Класс Point:

```
public class Point {
    
    public double x;
    public double y;
    public double z;
    
    public Point() {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        z = 0;
    }
    
    public Point(double x, double y, double z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

}
```

Все позиции по x, y, z — левые верхние края.

У меня есть метод:

```
    public void renderPixels(World world, Camera cam) {
        
        for (Object obj : world.objs) {
            
                for (Pixel curPix : obj.getPixels()) {
                            double x = (obj.getX() + curPix.x) - cam.getX();
                            double y = (obj.getY() + curPix.y) - cam.getY();
                            if (inRenderZone(x, y)) pixels[(int) x + (int) y * WIDTH] = curPix.color;
                }
        
        }
```

Тут pixels этого класса — цвета, закодированные в int в позициях, которые я потом перевожу на экран. `inRenderZone(double, double)` проверяет находится ли точка в пределах рендера. У объекта cam есть поле `public double zoom = 1;`

Мне надо рендерить каждый Object в мире (world.objs) так, чтобы в вычислениях кроме перевода в экранные координаты участвовал `cam.zoom`, и сохранялись все пропорции. Если найдутся реальные знатки, то еще желательно чтобы приближение было к центру камеры, а не к левому верхнему краю (позиции камеры). Фпс пока много, пишите как хотите ☺

Answer (score 0):

Забыл что надо менять положение объекта вместе с приближением камеры чтобы сохранить пропорции, вот что вышло по итогу:

```
public void renderPixels(World world, Camera cam) {
    
    for (Object obj : world.objs)
        for (Pixel curPix : obj.resizedPixels)
          
          for (double x = ((obj.getX() + curPix.x) - cam.getX()) * cam.zoom; x < ((obj.getX() + curPix.x) - cam.getX()) * cam.zoom + cam.zoom; x++)
            for (double y = ((obj.getY() + curPix.y) - cam.getY()) * cam.zoom; y <  ((obj.getY() + curPix.y) - cam.getY()) * cam.zoom + cam.zoom; y++)
              
              if (inRenderZone(x, y)) pixels[(int) x + (int) y * WIDTH] = curPix.color
  }
```